# KnockoutJS and HTML5 input color

Tags: html, knockout.js, color-picker

I have an HTML table and a foreach binding for tbody td.

Every td has html binding that use a function to generate different html element.

In one case, html element generated is a

```
<input type"color" />
```

but after creation, if I click on the input box, the color picker is not showed.

I think there is something wrong about knockoutjs context...isn't true?

Here a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qrj2omnh/)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your click-binding was preventing it from working. `Return true` in the callback fixes it:

```
self.fieldTypeHandler = function(row, prop){
    return true;
};
```